# Android Java открыть файл

Tags: java, android

Есть кнопка в андроид приложении, как сделать так, что если пользователь нажмет на нее, у него появится выбор файловых систем, он выберет систему и затем откроет какой то файл и передаст приложению?

Comment: задайте более развернутый вопрос. Напишите пример вашей логики реализации, пример кода или ошибки, которые получаете. Дайте больше информации

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files

Comment: Вопрос понятен и не надо его закрывать.

Answer (score 0):

1. До Kitkat, народ писал свои селекторы файлов, наиболее популярный из них [aFileChooser](https://github.com/iPaulPro/aFileChooser) - сейчас он уже морально устарел
2. Сейчас, православным способом считается старт `Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` через `startActivityForResult()` с последующим перехватом `onActivityResult()` - где вернется ссылка на выбранный файл. Ссылку на документацию с примерами см. выше в комментариях.